# Error -2146825284 / 0x800A0BBC when trying to write file

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a query which uses `sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2` to write from an `image` column to disk. It is failing with an error which I think relates to file permissions. `-2146825284 / 0x800A0BBC`. `@fPath` will contain something like `C:\exportdir\1\MI0033705\150916 Document1.pdf`

The export location is `C:\exportdir` on the sql server and the user account that runs the SQL service has full control of the folder. I have tested by logging in as the user (which happens to be a domain admin) and can write files manually no problem.

Calls to similar SPs work fine (sp_OACreate, sp_OASetProperty, etc), it's only when I try to write a file.

Is there some other permissions or settings I should be looking at to get this to work?

Code:

```
DECLARE @outPutPath varchar(100)
, @i bigint
, @init int
, @econtents varbinary(max) 
, @fPath varchar(max)  
, @folderPath  varchar(max) 
, @efolderName nvarchar(31)
, @efolderid nvarchar(250)
, @filename varchar(max)
, @ekey nvarchar(250)

--Get Data into temp Table variable so that we can iterate over it 
DECLARE @Doctable TABLE (id bigint identity(1,1), ekey  nvarchar(250) , esize int, [econtents] varbinary(max) )

INSERT INTO @Doctable([ekey], [esize],[econtents])
SELECT TOP 3 ekey, esize, econtents FROM eattachment ORDER BY newid();
--Select top 3 ekey, esize, econtents from eattachment
select * from @doctable

SELECT @i = 1

WHILE @i <= 3
BEGIN 
    SET @ekey = (SELECT ekey from @doctable where id = @i)
    SET @efolderid = (SELECT replace(replace(replace(RTRIM(LTRIM(STUFF(LEFT(@ekey,33),1,1,''))), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''),char(9),'') from @doctable where id = @i)
    SET @filename = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ekey, 35, LEN(@ekey))))
    SET @efoldername =  (select top 1 efoldername
                                    from efolder 
                                    where efolderid 
                                    like @efolderid
                                    )

    SELECT @ekey  as ekey
    SELECT @efolderid  as folder
    SELECT @efoldername  as foldername
    select @filename  as filename

    SET @outPutPath = N'C:\exportdir'

    SELECT 
     @econtents = (select [econtents] from @doctable where id = @i),
     @fPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ CAST([id] as varchar(21)) + '\' + @efolderName + '\' + @filename, 
     @folderPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ CAST([id] as varchar(21))
    FROM @Doctable WHERE id = @i

    select @econtents  as econtents
    select @fpath  as fpath
    select @folderpath  as folderpath

DECLARE @hr int;   
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d creating object (OACreate).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d setting property (OASetProperty).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END 

EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open';
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d opening method (OAMethod Open).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END 
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @econtents;
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d writing (OAMethod Write).', 16, 1, @hr) --THIS LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS!
    RETURN
END 
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d writing file (OAMethod SaveToFile).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END  
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close';
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d closing (OAMethod Close).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END  
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OADestroy @init; 
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d destroying (OADestroy).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END

print 'Document Generated at - '+  @fPath   

--Reset the variables for next use
SELECT @econtents = NULL  
, @init = NULL
, @fPath = NULL  
, @folderPath = NULL
, @hr = NULL
SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

eAttachment table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[eAttachment](
    [eKey] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [eSize] [int] NULL,
    [eContents] [image] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [ePKU_eAttachment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [eKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Error:

```
(3 row(s) affected)

(3 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 79
Error -2146825284 writing file (OAMethod SaveToFile).
```

Sample data

> ekey: `0  0000000000000000000000000179858 20180213114502 Filename.pdf`
>
> esize: `183958`
>
> econtents:
>   `0x7B35303146323335462D373546302D343936342D394137392D4145363335304242393138....
>   etc` 
>   (this is a very long string of characters)

Also here is a picture showing the current value of a lot of the variables for another example:

[image: Image showing some results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "minimally complete, verifiable, example" consists of reducing your code to the smallest set of viable commands required to reproduce or debug your error.

Since you're having an issue with the `sp_OAMethod` call to `SaveToFile`, you don't need to present all the details around the tables you have, etc, etc.

I distilled your code down to this:

```
DECLARE @hr int;   
DECLARE @init int;
DECLARE @fPath varchar(260);
DECLARE @econtents varbinary(100);

SET @fPath = 'C:\temp\test_ADODB.Stream.txt';
SET @econtents = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(100);

EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d creating object (OACreate).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d setting property (OASetProperty).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END 

EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open';
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d opening method (OAMethod Open).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END 
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @econtents;
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d writing (OAMethod Write).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END 
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d writing file (OAMethod SaveToFile).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END  
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close';
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d closing (OAMethod Close).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END  
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OADestroy @init; 
IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d destroying (OADestroy).', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END

print 'Document Generated at - '+  @fPath
```

My SQL Server has access to the `C:\TEMP` folder, and this code in fact works as expected.  This leads me to believe there is a problem generating the file name in your code prior to the `sp_OA...` code.

Performing some further troubleshooting of your code, I see it works correctly assuming the required folders exist, and SQL Server has access to them:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.efolder', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.efolder;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.eAttachment', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.eAttachment;

CREATE TABLE dbo.efolder
(
    efolderid nvarchar(250) NOT NULL
    , efoldername varchar(260) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.efolder (efolderid, efoldername)
VALUES ('11111111111111111111111111111111', 'efoldername')
    , ('22222222222222222222222222222222', 'efoldername')
    , ('33333333333333333333333333333333', 'efoldername');

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[eAttachment](
    [eKey] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [eSize] [int] NULL,
    [eContents] [image] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [ePKU_eAttachment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [eKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];

INSERT INTO dbo.eAttachment (eKey, eSize, eContents)
VALUES ('11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111', 100, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(100))
    , ('22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222', 100, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(100))
    , ('33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333', 100, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(100));

DECLARE @outPutPath varchar(100)
, @i bigint
, @init int
, @econtents varbinary(1000) 
, @fPath varchar(max)  
, @folderPath  varchar(max) 
, @efolderName nvarchar(31)
, @efolderid nvarchar(250)
, @filename varchar(max)
, @ekey nvarchar(250)

--Get Data into temp Table variable so that we can iterate over it 
DECLARE @Doctable TABLE (id bigint identity(1,1), ekey  nvarchar(250) , esize int, [econtents] varbinary(max) )

INSERT INTO @Doctable([ekey], [esize],[econtents])
SELECT TOP 3 ekey, esize, econtents FROM eattachment ORDER BY newid();
--Select top 3 ekey, esize, econtents from eattachment
select * from @doctable

SELECT @i = 1

WHILE @i <= 3
BEGIN 
    PRINT N'Loop #' + CONVERT(nchar(1), @i);
    SET @ekey = (SELECT ekey from @doctable where id = @i)
    SET @efolderid = (SELECT replace(replace(replace(RTRIM(LTRIM(STUFF(LEFT(@ekey,33),1,1,''))), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''),char(9),'') from @doctable where id = @i)
    SET @filename = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ekey, 35, LEN(@ekey))))
    SET @efoldername =  (select top 1 efoldername
                                    from efolder 
                                    where efolderid 
                                    like @efolderid
                                    )
    SELECT @efolderid as efolderid;
    SELECT @ekey  as ekey
    SELECT @efolderid  as folder
    SELECT @efoldername  as foldername
    select @filename  as filename

    SET @outPutPath = N'C:\temp'

    SELECT 
     @econtents = (select [econtents] from @doctable where id = @i),
     @fPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ CAST([id] as varchar(21)) + '\' + @efolderName + '\' + @filename, 
     @folderPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ CAST([id] as varchar(21))
    FROM @Doctable WHERE id = @i

    select @econtents  as econtents
    select @fpath  as fpath
    select @folderpath  as folderpath

    DECLARE @folderCheck varchar(1000);
    SET @folderCheck = 'mkdir ' + @folderPath + '\' + @efolderName;
    EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell @folderCheck;

    DECLARE @hr int;   
    PRINT N'EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate ''ADODB.Stream'', @init OUTPUT';
    EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT
    IF @hr <> 0  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR('Error %d creating object (OACreate).', 16, 1, @hr)
        RETURN
    END
    PRINT N'EXECUTE @hr = sp_OASetProperty @init, ''Type'', 1;'
    EXECUTE @hr = sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;
    IF @hr <> 0  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR('Error %d setting property (OASetProperty).', 16, 1, @hr)
        RETURN
    END 
    PRINT N'EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, ''Open'';';
    EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open';
    IF @hr <> 0  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR('Error %d opening method (OAMethod Open).', 16, 1, @hr)
        RETURN
    END 
    PRINT N'EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, ''Write'', NULL, @econtents;'
    EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @econtents;
    IF @hr <> 0  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR('Error %d writing (OAMethod Write).', 16, 1, @hr) --THIS LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS!
        RETURN
    END 
    PRINT N'EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, ''SaveToFile'', NULL, @fPath, 2'
    EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2
    IF @hr <> 0  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR('Error %d writing file (OAMethod SaveToFile).', 16, 1, @hr)
        RETURN
    END  
    PRINT N'EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, ''Close'';'
    EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close';
    IF @hr <> 0  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR('Error %d closing (OAMethod Close).', 16, 1, @hr)
        RETURN
    END  
    PRINT N'EXECUTE @hr = sp_OADestroy @init;'
    EXECUTE @hr = sp_OADestroy @init; 
    IF @hr <> 0  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR('Error %d destroying (OADestroy).', 16, 1, @hr)
        RETURN
    END

    print 'Document Generated at - '+  @fPath   

    --Reset the variables for next use
    SELECT @econtents = NULL  
    , @init = NULL
    , @fPath = NULL  
    , @folderPath = NULL
    , @hr = NULL;

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

The output from the "Messages" tab:

```
Loop #1
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open';
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @econtents;
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close';
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OADestroy @init;
Document Generated at - C:\temp\1\efoldername\3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
Loop #2
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open';
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @econtents;
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close';
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OADestroy @init;
Document Generated at - C:\temp\2\efoldername\1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Loop #3
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open';
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @econtents;
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close';
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OADestroy @init;
Document Generated at - C:\temp\3\efoldername\2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
```

FYI, the error number you're seeing is `adErrWriteFile` according to Microsoft's [Error Code Lookup Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985)<sup>1</sup>, which has the following explanation, according to the [Microsoft Docs ADO Error Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/ado-error-reference):

> Write to file failed. You might have closed a file and then tried to write to it, or the file might be corrupted. If the file is located on a network drive, transient network conditions might prevent writing to a network drive.

---

<sup>1 - Yes, this is billed as the "Exchange" error lookup tool, however it functions equally well for almost all Microsoft products</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has found themselves here, ensure the your SQL Server has permissions to write to your dir! Documentation on how to provision is shown below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017